# RelativeLayout inside Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, navigation-drawer

i'm implementing `Navigation Drawer`, it works ok , but i want to position a custom EditText inside of a RelativeLayout , but some `RelativeLayout` attributes like `layout_centerInParent` are missing and i can't assign those to my custom EditText :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@string/activity_search_color">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@string/bg_color" >

        <com.xxx.xxx.Buttons.CustomEditText 
            xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xxx.xxx"
            android:id="@+id/edt_box"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            custom:typeface="bold"
            style="@style/edtstyle"
        />


    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/black"
    android:dividerHeight="0.0dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_nav"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
```

where is my mistake? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved the issue with including another layout which is RelativeLayout inside FrameLayout